# Archimedean components of base changed automorphic representations

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms

Let $\pi$ be an automorphic (cuspidal) representation of ${\rm GL}(n)_{/\Bbb Q}$.

Let $K\supset\Bbb Q$ a numberfield. The existence of the base change lift $\pi_K$ is known in a number of cases.

What is the recipe to write the archimedean components $\pi_{K,v}$ (i.e. for $v\mid\infty$) in terms of the explicit description of $\pi_\infty$?

Is there a reference?

(an answer in the case $n=2$ would be already helpful, I don't expect the general case to be substantially different)

Comment: Did you look in Arthur-Clozel?